# Как можно передать объект из Питона в ЯваСкрипт

Tags: javascript, python, клиент-сервер

На сервере работает Python-скрипт (Bottle), который генерирует около 10-15 переменных, содержащих списки значений. Как бы их передать ЯваСкрипту, чтобы он построил графики?

Самый отчаянный способ, это запись всех значений в HTML через скрытые поля, но как-то топорно...

Второй способ: упаковать в JSON и записать его в JS-файл, который будет импортироваться страницей до основного скрипта.
Но что будет, если несколько пользователей одновременно откроют/обновят страницу?

Третий способ - сделать правильно и вот тут я прошу вашей помощи.

Comment: генерируйте json и вставляйте его внутрь страницы. Если несколько пользователей запросят страницу, то каждый получит свою (делайте поддерку сессий, если нужно чуть более сложная логика).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ну представь ты себе как клиент-сервер работает

сервер один, он генерит контент, который выполняется на стороне клиента.

сто клиентов подключилось - сто бочек контента появилось на стороне клиента.

каждому клиенту в бочку льешь уникальный js и все.

т.е. ты просто рендеришь на сервере блок js  с теми переменными, которые подходят твоему клиенту.
на сервере, условно говоря:

```
print ("<script language='text/javascript'>alert("+ random.randint(1, 10) + ")</script>")
```

на клиенте получится, например

```
<script language='text/javascript'>alert(6)</script>
```

если ты пишешь в скрытые поля формы - это, фактически то же самое, что ты пишешь в js. и js и html - все улетает к клиенту и клиент уже интерпретирует эти данные как хочет.

Answer (score 2):

Может, через ajax ?

Страница на стороне клиента когда будет готова (например, можно сделать сразу в момент её загрузки) отправляет серверу ajax-запрос, в ответ получает значения нужных переменных, и строит по ним всё что угодно.

Хотя, в способе писать прямо в html тоже ничего плохого нет. Можно не в скрытые поля, а сделать тег script и внутри него инициализировать нужные переменные нужными значениями.

Comment: через ajax норм, когда подгружаешь новые данные. первый результат лучше напрямую выдать в script, впрочем да, тоже вариант, чтобы не копошиться

Comment: ajax - лучше когда требуется скрыть данные, допускается кеш средствами сервера, хочется уменьшить размер html файла.